# What does 'virus resistance' do in Worm.is?

Tags: worm.is

In the game *Worms.is: The Game* on [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/app/466910/Wormis_The_Game/) (a copy of *Slither.io*), there is an item property called 'virus resistance', for example of this "Shield of the Ancient Tarantula":

[image]

I *think* it might be decisive for the duration or intensity of 'viruses' that other players shoot at you, but I wonder if it (also) has an effect on other aspects of the game.

Does anyone know?